# What is best way to link Sage Line 50 with Salesforce?

Tags: integration

What is the best way to create an app in Salesforce with information in Sage Line 50. Any ideas?

UPDATE: There is a back-up option in Sage line 50 that can be restored later. But that is not human readable. Can anyone tell me how should I proceed to integrate with Salesforce.

Comment: What integration or data extraction possibilities exist for Sage Line 50 ? That might be your starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Integration page](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Integration%20ss) on developer.force.com is a good starting point.

There are a lot of options, but that will give you an idea of how to begin planning.